# Eclipse (Galileo) : Why does "Initializing Java Tooling : 59%" take FOREVER?

Tags: java, eclipse, load, delay, eclipse-3.5

New to Java and Eclipse.  For some reason, the first time I load Eclipse on a given day, it freezes at "Initializing Java Tooling : 59%".  Eventually, it gets past this and I can do my work.  However, this "Initializing Java Tooling : 59%" stage takes a REALLY REALLY REALLY long time.  Does anybody know why it does this or how to fix it?

Comment: It may be having to scan through all your projects to do the initialization. It depends on which tool is being initialized, without that, everything is guessing.  Just start Eclipse, go get a cup of coffee and hope it is up when you are done drinking it. :)

Comment: Play with the vm settings. Maybe eclipse gets faster at this stage if it gets more memory.

Comment: It may be due to the number and size of the projects that eclipse has to open when it's loading. I've noticed in the past that the more projects it has to load, especialy if they are large, as it's loading causes the tool initialization to take forever. I have since switched to NetBeans and imo NetBeans is a much better IDE to use.

Answer (score 6):

You can take several thread dumps of the Eclipse Java process to see what plugins are being executed. Here is [some info](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javapedia/ThreadDump) on how to take thread dumps.

What happen is that Eclipse loads all project configurations and then for each project it initializes all declared builders. The builder loading and initialization is what takes most of the time. Some builders need to resolve and/or reload project dependencies such as jars and other projects and also check if project resources had changed. This process can also trigger initialization of builders on other projects and it may take longer depending on 3rd party plugins you are using.

Answer (score 4):

It breaks on a per workspace basis. I have had some success removing plugin data. Usually this can be found by at:-

```
[workspace-directory]/.metadata/.plugins
```

If you delete everything except:-

```
org.eclipse.core.resources
```

You will keep your projects but everything else will be deleted (preferences, scm repositories ... etc.) and will need to be recreated/reimported (you will be greeted by the welcome page, but do not be alarmed).

There is probably a specific set of plugin data that should be deleted, but this fixed my last occurence, and so I have nothing else against which to further hone in on the problem state ... for the time being.

Comment: This fixed the problem, but didn't save any preferences. Oh well - easily restored!

Answer (score 2):

Following mike's advice, I resurrected my workspace by just deleting `[workspace-directory]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core`. That directory doesn't seem to store any important information.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me and I had to resort to deleting every .plugin directory - which did fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found a solution here:

http://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/eclipse-initializing-java-tooling-hangs/
Here's what I did.

```
Rename the .projects folder in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources 
in the workspace folder. This doesn’t seem to affect any project and 
the .project folder will be recreated when Eclipse restarts.
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple-minded approach than Eugene's very clever one is to remove all your plugins, one by one, keep notes, and watch performance after each removal. This should help pinpoint the plugin that's doing the big initialization. It's possible that you didn't really need that plugin after all.

In my experience, there is often a big delay associated with source control plugins because some feel the need to check project state against the repository on startup. There may be options to control this. You can also look at what kind of label decoration is in effect; if some decoration is dependent on repository state, that could be your time waster right there.

Be warned that this procedure may be destructive! You probably included those plugins for a reason, and if you remove the plugins it's possible you'll lose capabilities on already present projects, and that even replacing the plugins will not necessarily restore everything in all projects to the former state. As the disk repartition people say: We assume that you have everything backed up!

Comment: Recommend you save off a copy of your eclipse folder and workspace folder before the test so you can restore it after you find the offending plugin.

Comment: Interesting.  I do indeed have a source control plugin.  Anybody ever have this issue with the Perforce plugin?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the following

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck "Build Automatically" and force quit Eclipse. Then start it again.
Project>Build Automatically - uncheck
-force quit
-start Eclipse